# KeyTyped method says TextField is blank ... when it's not

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, keylistener

```
        Jtxtfield.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {};
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if(Jtxtfield.getText().equals(""))
            System.out.println("hello1");
        }public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if(Jtxtfield.getText().equals(""))
            System.out.println("hello2");
        }
    });
```

Output for the first key pressed (say, 'a') is: hello1. 
If I press a second key (say, 'a' again), there is no output (as expected). 
If I press the delete key twice, I get hello1 hello2.

Why is this happening? Why does the keyTyped Method treating txtfield as though it had nothing in there? More specifically, why do I get only hello1 when I press a key that is the first key pressed in the text field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text field fires three events: a key pressed event, a key typed event, and a key released event, in sequence. The key typed event doesn't have key code information; they also don't have modifier information. If you care only about which characters the user types, you should handle key typed events. If you care about which keys the user presses/releases, you should handle key pressed/released events.

If you want the value of the textfield use keyReleased(KeyEvent e) as

```
JTextField txt = (JTextField) e.getSource();
System.out.println(txt.getText());
```

An example you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/KeyEventDemoProject/src/events/KeyEventDemo.java)

Also you can use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html).

Comment: So... How does this answer my question?